# SQL 2000: Variables in update statements and order of evaluation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an **update** statement in this form:

```
declare @v as int
update tbl
set @v=tbl.a=(select sum(amount) from anothertable at where at.x = tbl.y),
    tbl.b = @v/2
```

The reason I would like to use a variable is to avoid using the subquery twice. The problem is that I have not found any references stating that this is safe. Is the second assignment (i.e. tbl.b = @v/2) always evaluated after the first assignment?

The order of evaluation for a **select** statement is not guaranteed. Is this also true for an update statement?

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could rid yourself the worry about order of evaluation with this:

```
UPDATE tbl
SET tbl.a = s.theSum,
    tbl.b = s.theSum / 2
FROM tbl
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT x, SUM(amount) AS thesum
    FROM anothertable
    GROUP BY x
) s ON s.x = tbl.y
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL is a declarative language. Don't try to do imperative constructs in it. This is not `C`.
The order of evaluation is not guaranteed in any statement (SELECT, DELETE, UPDATE, MERGE, INSERT, really, any).

Comment: Microsoft states it clearly for the "Select" statements but not for the update statements.

Do you have any doc references about the update statement?